# Cannot get hyperlinks in emails

Tags: asp.net, email, razor

**What I am doing:** I was creating an email update for users, which would tell them that there has been a Password reset for their account.

**What code I am using:** I am using `ASP.NET Razor/Web Pages` to write the code. And Gmail's smtp server to send emails. After the password reset code, I have put `WebMail.Send()` in the block. Like the following one:

```
Response.Write(@"Password reset success! '
Next time login with your new password.");
WebMail.Send(to: WebSecurity.CurrentUserName,
subject: "Password changed for your account",
body: @"Hello " + name + @".<br>
// don't mind the remaining part, its just the bla bla as most sites send..
```

**What I recieve as Email:** What I recieve as email is just the text that I wrote. But the issue is simple and somehow it will be just a line or a second to tackle that, but I am not able to get where I am getting error. here is the image for the email.

[image: email..]

In both image the words that are in circle are hyperlinks. I uses `<a href='localhost:5878/contact'>Contact Us</a> to create them. But all that I get is`Contact us`without any`href` in it.

The image for that is:

[image]

**What I have done for this:** I have searched for this issue. But sometimes I get result for Silverlight project, or sometimes I get the answer for PHP or something like. I need help for `ASP.NET Razor/Web Pages` or even, tell me what am I doing wrong? Why can't `href` be sent in email body? Am I doing something wrong(I am sure I am)? I was not able to find help, so I had to post a question.

Comment: What is the actual source code of the e-mail? Have you tried sending it out with the href going to localhost?

Comment: You're closing the `href=''` in the wrong place in your example. You need the `'` between contact and your closing tag like so:  `contact'>`.

Comment: I am really really sorry about that @John, I just made a correction for that. I misused `'` with `.

Comment: Was that the issue or just a typo in the question?

Comment: nah I didnt try that @Ek0nomik.

Comment: typo in the question. The real code in the block is this: `<a href='localhost:5878/contact' target='_blank'>Contact Us</a>`

Comment: Put a break point on the line where it's sending the email. From there, you can check if it's really sending what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer from a person. So I wanted to share it here too.

The issue was the URL, that was being blocked by sites `localhost:5878`. So the person told me to change the `href` from `localhost:5878` to `http://localhost:5878`. After trying out this. I was able to get the links working. They were not blocked either in the Email provider.

The point that I mentioned about the email blockage was about Outlook. In my outlook account when I clicked over links I saw a message, "For you security this is disabled, want to enable it?" I am not perfect while writing it again. But it sounded the same! Which meant that the link was blocked.

And after adding `href` it wasn't blocked any more. Is it a known issue while sending emails with a link that has a port name too, like `:5878`?

Please let me know about it.